# Why does NR==FNR; {} behave differently when used as NR==FNR{ }?

Tags: awk

Hoping someone can help explain the following `awk` output.
`awk --version`: GNU Awk 5.0.1, API: 2.0 (GNU MPFR 4.0.2, GNU MP 6.2.0)
OS: Linux sub system on Windows; Linux Windows11x64 5.10.102.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2
user experience: n00b

**Important**: In the two code snippets below, the only difference is the semi colon ( ; ) after `NR==FNR` in sample # 2.

sample # 1
`'awk 'NR==FNR { print $0 }' lines_to_show.txt all_lines.txt`
output # 1
2
3
4
5
7

sample # 2
`'awk 'NR==FNR; { print $0 }' lines_to_show.txt all_lines.txt`
output # 2
2 # why is value in file 'lines_to_show.txt appearing twice?
2
3
3
4
4
5
5
7
7
line    -01
line    -02
line    -03
line    -04
line    -05
line    -06
line    -07
line    -08
line    -09
line    -10

**Generate the text input files**
**lines_to_show.txt**: `echo -e "2\n3\n4\n5\n7" > lines_to_show.txt`
**all_lines.txt**: `echo -e "line\t-01\nline\t-02\nline\t-03\nline\t-04\nline\t-05\nline\t-06\nline\t-07\nline\t-08\nline\t-09\nline\t-10" > all_lines.txt`

**Request/Questions**:

- If you can please explain why you know the answers to the questions below (experience, tutorial, video, etc..)
- How does one read an `awk' program? I was under the impression that a semi colon ( ; ) is only a statement terminator, just like in C. It should not have an impact on the execution of the program.
- In output # 2, why are the values in the file 'lines_to_show.txt appearing twice? Seems like `awk` is printing values from the 1st file "lines_to_show.txt" but printing them 10 times, which is the number of records in the file "all_lines.txt". Is this true? why?
- Why in output # 1, only output from "lines_to_show.txt" is displayed? I thought `awk` will process each record in each file, so I expcted to see 15 lines (10 + 5).

**What have I tried so far?**

1. going though https://www.linkedin.com/learning/awk-essential-training/using-awk-command-line-flags?autoSkip=true&autoplay=true&resume=false&u=61697657
2. modifying the code to see the difference and use that to 'understand' what is going on.
3. trying to work through the flow using pen and paper
4. going through https://www.baeldung.com/linux/awk-multiple-input-files --> https://www.baeldung.com/linux/awk-multiple-input-files

Comment: In a C program, or any other language you know that terminates statements with `;`s, why is `if (foo) bar;` different from `if (foo); bar`? Same thing for awk.

Answer (score 2):

```
awk 'NR==FNR { print $0 }' lines_to_show.txt all_lines.txt
```

Here you have one pattern-action pair, that is if (total) number of row equals file number of row then print whole line.

```
awk 'NR==FNR; { print $0 }' lines_to_show.txt all_lines.txt
```

Here you have two pattern-action pairs, as `;` follows condition it is assumed that you want *default action* which is `{print $0}`, in other words that is equivalent to

```
awk 'NR==FNR{print $0}{ print $0}' lines_to_show.txt all_lines.txt
```

first `print $0` is used solely when processing 1st file, 2nd `print $0` is used indiscriminately (no condition given), so for `lines_to_show.txt` both `print`s are used, for `all_lines.txt` solely 2nd `print`.

Comment: "pattern action" or "condition rule"? (either way, I knew what you meant `:)`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I use *pattern* and *action* in same meaning as [The GNU Awk User's Guide](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Getting-Started) do

Comment: I had to read the answer a few times but now I understand what is going on. Thanks! @Daweo. Sorry, I cannot upvote as I don't have enough points.

Comment: @Daweo - nothing wrong with that, you already got my vote. The manual is always correct, though common jargon of "condition" and "rule" is likely more descriptive. E.g. while a regex is a pattern, it's hard to call `NR == 1` or `n > 2`, etc.. a pattern. Good citation to the manual.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin the POSIX spec uses pattern/action. "Pattern" is defined: `A pattern is any valid expression, a range specified by two expressions separated by a comma, or one of the two special patterns BEGIN or END`.

Comment: All the docs use the word "pattern" and they're all misleading. The modern awk language is condition-action pairs where there's a condition followed by the action to perform if that condition is true. In the mid-70s when awk was first invented it did indeed mostly match patterns against input text in that context but it does far more than that now. If awk was invented and documented today no-one would be using the word "pattern" for the condition part and it's far clearer to tell newcomers the syntax is condition-action than have them try to figure out what a "pattern" means.

Comment: even calling it "condition" doesn't capture the entirety of it - it's more like anything that allows for boolean evaluation, including arbitrary strings ::::::   e.g.  gawk FS  :::: is actually a valid awk script - because it evaluated the default space ( " " ) of FS as a non-empty string, so everything gets printed, including blank lines. However, ::::::: gawk +FS :::: prints out absolutely nothing, cuz unary plus "+" forced it to first convert to numeric, ( +" " ) becomes a zero ( 0 ) , so all input lines evaluated to false, and nothing can ever print

Comment: Oh I read it. They just use `rule == pattern + action`.  No beef with it, only quibble is with the `"pattern"` usage being a bit misleading as whether a regex or conditional expression is described. The manual uses `"pattern"` for both.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin [book written by Aho, Kernighan, Weinberger](https://archive.org/details/pdfy-MgN0H1joIoDVoIC7) use pattern to describe both regular expression and comparison, for example `$2 >= 5` is called *comparison pattern* (page 9). I do not felel myself in position to countermand what said author said

Comment: By all means, there is no need to. If that's what he wants to call it, and he is the one writing the manual, then his literary liberty in that regard is fine. The crux of my comment has to do with dealing with all GNU tools, such as `awk`, `sed`, `bash`, etc.. Where a pattern is generally a regex or a glob and a conditional expression tests a condition (thus the `"CONDITIONAL EXPRESSIONS"` section of `man bash`).  Or there is no such thing as a non-regex pattern in GNU `sed`. But, he who writes the manual can take liberty to call it whatever they want. (and it is a great manual too)

Answer (score 0):

`man awk` is the best reference:

```
An awk program is composed of pairs of the form:

pattern { action }

Either the pattern or the action (including the
enclosing brace characters) can be omitted.

A missing pattern shall match any record of input,
and a missing action shall be equivalent to:

{ print }
```

`;` terminates a pattern-action block. So   you have two pattern/action blocks, both whose action is to print the line.